# Copy of a large amount of selected data

Tags: linux, bash, file-copy

I would like to extract some files distributed in various repertories with an automatic procedure.

My files are untilted:

```
"dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.PRESSURE"
"dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.RHO"
"dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.VELOCITY"
```

where X is a number between 0 and 1500.

They are distributed in repertories named `repY`, where Y is a number between 39 and 69.

Each repertory contains approximately 50 files of each type (PRESSURE, RHO, and VELOCITY), and is located in the path denoted `path/instantaneous_fields/`.

`rep39` contains:

```
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.PRESSURE
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.RHO
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.VELOCITY
```

for X from 1 to Z0, where Z0 is approximately 50 (can be between 46 and 54).

`rep40` contains:

```
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.PRESSURE
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.RHO
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.VELOCITY
```

for X from Z0+1 to Z1, where Z1 is approximately 100 (can be between 96 and 104).

`rep41` contains:

```
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.PRESSURE
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.RHO
dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.VELOCITY
```

for X from Z1+1 to Z2. *etc*

I would like to copy only the files charaterized by a decade number (X=10, X=20, X=30, ..., X=1500) into a new repertory called "selected_files", located in the same path: `path/instantaneous_fields/`.

I don't know how to only select the decade numbers. Could you help me?

Moreover, as each file weigh 2.5 GB, the volume copied is large (2.5GB*3 type of files*150 files=1.125 TB), I am looking for a more adapted command than `cp` if there is one.

I have the algorithm but no knowledge in the bash syntax:

```bsh
for Y from 39 to 69
cd repY
max_X = X maximum
for X from 0 to max_X by step of 10
cp dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.PRESSURE dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.RHO dns_lata_X.sauv.lata.0.VELOCITY ../selected_files
```

Comment: Will the files change after they've been copied the first time? Will you be adding new ones that also need copying?

Comment: As far as I can see, you will have `rep39/dns_lata_10.sauv.lata.0.RHO` and `rep40/dns_lata_10.sauv.lata.0.RHO`. When these are copied to a single directory the second file will overwrite the first because the filenames are the same.